# Python, FFT and DC offset analysis

Tags: python, fft, offset, dc

I test an FFT on a square signal (100Hz, 0V-5V) of 50% duty cycle and i don't understand why my DC offset is huge ?

In theory it should be 2.5V ?

Thanks,
Best regards.

*The fundamental is ok and others harmonics are correct.*

[square signal 100Hz, TTL compatible 0V-5V, 50% duty cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH3sC.png)

[FFT, DC offset problem, fundamental ok, harmonics ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrhhD.png)

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#
# configuration
# time analyse = L * (1/Fsample)
#
L = 512 # lenght buffer
Fsample = 2000 # frequency sample
Fsignal = 100 # frequency

#********************************

# perdiode sample
Tsample = 1.0/Fsample

# time vector, start = 0s, stop = 0.1024s, step = (0.1024s / (1/Fe))
t = np.linspace(0.0, L*Tsample, L)

# signal definition, DC offet = 2.5V, Amplitude = 2.5V
signal = 2.5 + 2.5*signal.square(2 * np.pi * Fsignal * t, 0.5)

# plot time signal
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t, signal)

# fft of time signal
yf = fft(signal)

# time vector of fft 
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*Tsample), L//2)

# plot spectral
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/L * np.abs(yf[0:L//2]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last line, the normalization factor was wrong.

It was not `2/L` but `1/L`.

The correct normalization factor `plt.plot(xf, 1.0/L * np.abs(yf[0:L//2]))`

The code work fine now !

[FFT correct amplitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRGnJ.png)